# Local extrema points of a function of two variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

i need to find local extrema points of a function of two variables, but it doesnt work

```
FindMaximum[x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, {x, y}]
```

I have this error:

```
FindMaximum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a maximum; it may be a minimum or a saddle point.
```

Comment: saddle point.  `Plot3D[x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}] ` It is always a good idea to plot the given functions to ge an overview.

Comment: @Akku14 yes, i know it, but i need specific answer (number) of max local extreme point

Comment: `Solve[Thread[D[x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, {{x, y}}] == 0], {x, y}] ` yields `{{x -> -1, y -> -1}, {x -> 1, y -> -1}, {x -> -1, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, 
  y -> 1}}`  `Plot3D[x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] `

Comment: Just to compare: see [SecondDerivativeTest](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/MultivariateCalculus/SecondDerivativeTest) of Maple. There is  room for improvement  in this topic in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If $D f(x,y)=0$ and $\mathrm{Hessian}f(x,y)$ is a positive definite matrix,then $f(x,y)$ get the local minimal.
- If $D f(x,y)=0$ and $\mathrm{Hessian}f(x,y)$ is a negative definite matrix,then $f(x,y)$ get the local minimal.

We use `Grad[f[x,y],{x,y}]` or `D[f[x,y],{{x,y},1}]` and `D[f[x,y],{{x,y},2}` to calculate the Gradient and Hessian.

And we know that a matrix `A={{a,b},{c,d}}` is positive definite if `a>0` and `Det[A]>0`, and a matrix `A={{a,b},{c,d}}` is negative definitee if `a<0` and `Det[A]>0`.

```
Clear[f, localmin, localmax];
f[x_, y_] = x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y;
localmin = 
  Solve[{D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}] == 0, 
    Det[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}][[;; 1, ;; 1]]] > 0, 
    Det[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}][[;; 2, ;; 2]]] > 0}, {x, y}];
localmax = 
  Solve[{D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 1}] == 0, 
    Det[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}][[;; 1, ;; 1]]] < 0, 
    Det[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}][[;; 2, ;; 2]]] > 0}, {x, y}];

Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[20], {Blue, 
    Point[{x, y, f[x, y]}] /. localmin}, {Red, 
    Point[{x, y, f[x, y]}] /. localmax}, Arrowheads[.02], 
   Arrow[{# + {0, 0, 10}, #} &@{x, y, f[x, y]} /. localmin], 
   Text["local min", {x, y, f[x, y]} + {0, 0, 10} /. localmin, 
    Background -> Yellow],
   Arrow[{# + {0, 0, 10}, #} &@{x, y, f[x, y]} /. localmax], 
   Text["local max", {x, y, f[x, y]} + {0, 0, 10} /. localmax, 
    Background -> Yellow]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

- The same as

```
FindMaximum[{x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5}, {x,
   y}]
FindMinimum[{x^3 - 2 y^3 - 3 x + 6 y, -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5}, {x,
   y}]
```

> `{6., {x -> -1., y -> 1.}}`

> `{-6., {x -> 1., y -> -1.}}`